# Using [FromQuery] to parse enum values

Tags: asp.net-core, enums, .net-core, html-parsing

I'm using the `[FromQuery]` attribute to parse a `Get` requests arguments into a complex object. For example:

```
[HttpGet("some-get-request")]
public IActionResult DoSomething([FromQuery] SomeArguments someArgs)
{

}
```

One of the properties of the `SomeArguments` object is an `enum`.

```
public enum SomeEnum { EnumValue01, EnumValue02 }

public class SomeArguments 
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "enum_arg")]
    public SomeEnum EnumArgument { get; set; }
}
```

And I call the endpoint with something like:

> http://localhost:1234/api/some-controller/some-get-request?enum_arg=EnumValue01

And this all works great. However, I want to be able to use a different enum value in the URL than in my C# enum value. For example, I want to call using a URL such as

> http://localhost:1234/api/some-controller/some-get-request?enum_arg=*eval01*

How can I do this?

I thought I could use the [FromQuery] attribute, like I can with properties, but that doesnt seem to be possible:

> 'FromQuery' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, parameter'

Comment: what do you mean by " I want to be able to use a different enum value in the URL than in my C# enum value" , what is your requirement

Comment: I would like the C# enum value to be one thing (EnumValue01, for example), but the value in the HTTP request to be something else (eval01, for example).

Comment: Then why not just use string as type , you can then map/modify that value to enum on server side .

Comment: Using a string is an option, but one I would like to avoid, if possible. Yes, it would allow any value for the parameter, which I can validate and handle in the code, however I dont want to do this if there's already a way to achieve what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 12):

You can use `EnumMemberAttribute` in conjunction with `StringEnumConverter` to achieve your goal. Define `SomeEnum` as following

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum SomeEnum
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "eval01")]
    EnumValue01,

    [EnumMember(Value = "eval02")]
    EnumValue02
}
```

At this point it will work as you need only when `Newtonsoft` json serializer is used. For example, when controller expects `POST` request and parameter is marked as `[FromBody]`. In your case it won't work yet because during binding of `[FromQuery]` parameter json serializer is not used. To solve this one create [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```cs
public class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string rawData = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).FirstValue;
        rawData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rawData); //turns value to valid json
        try
        {
            SomeEnum result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeEnum>(rawData); //manually deserializing value
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        }
        catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
        {
            //do nothing since "failed" result is set by default
        }


        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Update `SomeEnum` definition to use `JsonModelBinder`

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
[ModelBinder(typeof(JsonModelBinder))]
public enum SomeEnum
```

Comment: Hello @Alexander , I have the same problem than this question owner, why when I have an enumvalue with a dash like `[EnumMember(Value = "test-enum")]` I need your jsonmodelbinder. But when I don't have a dash like `[EnumMember(Value = "testenum")]` the modelbinder isn't necessary ?

Comment: @Neyoh What do you meand by *the modelbinder isn't necessary* in ceratain cases? It's always required to use the binder to make `EnumMember` work

Comment: In this exemple, when I remove the dash like `Value = "testuno")`, it works without the modelbinder. https://gist.github.com/Kyochi/c46afe423facb1c4fde37f4fed33e9f0

Comment: @Neyoh What version of ASP.NET Core are you using? And do you mark your controller with `[ApiController]` attribute?

Comment: @Neyoh If you remove dash from `test-uno` in you example the name will just match with `TestUno` member name that's why it works. Try `[EnumMemberAttribute(Value = "uno")] ` which is without dash and see how it works

Comment: Yes I'm using [ApiController] and ASPNET core 2.2.0.

Comment: You right, when I use `uno`, I got an exception like  `The type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter' must implement 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IModelBinder' to be used as a model binder.\r\nParameter name: binderType"`

Comment: I don't understand well what is the role of the modelbinder

Comment: This didn't work for me in .NET 6.
Using controllers extending `ControllerBase` and `[FromQuery]`
The `JsonModelBinder` does not even trigger.