# Use an enum when passing a parameter through SupplyParameterFromQuery

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, query-string, .net-8.0

I am trying to use an `enum` type (to avoid hard-coding the values) when passing a parameter through `SupplyParameterFromQuery` as follow:

**Counter.razor**

```cs
  public enum EnumType { One, Two, Three }

  [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
  public EnumType Number { get; set; }
```

**Index.razor**

```html
@using static BlazorApp1.Pages.Counter
<a href="/counter?Number=@EnumType.One" >counter page: One</a>
```

When issuing the above GET request I hit the exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Querystring values cannot be parsed as type 'BlazorApp1.Pages.Counter+EnumType'....

I have searched similar questions like [Using [FromQuery] to parse enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56826539/5228202)
but unfortunately couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Is there a way to cast enum somehow or defining a custom converter (if not an overkill) ? How to overcome that ?

Comment: Web App, Server App or Wasm App ?

Comment: @ℍℍ server app, in this case i don't think the app type will change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably have to convert it to and then back from an int.

Not elegant!

```cs
public enum NumberEnum
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3
}
```

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@($"/counter?Test={(int)_numberEnum}")">@($"Send {_numberEnum}")</a>
</div>

@code {
    private NumberEnum _numberEnum = NumberEnum.Three;
}
```

```cs
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<p class="mt-3 bg-dark text-white p-1" role="status">Enum: @_numberEnum</p>

@code {
    [Parameter, SupplyParameterFromQuery] public int Test { get; set; }
    private NumberEnum _numberEnum => (NumberEnum)Test;

    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, if there will be no other answer i believe i will just go with this i have to cast it when sending parameter and cast it again when doing a test in code.

Comment: Based on the example in the question, the OP is attempting to pass the enum via the query string as a string rather than its underlying value. So your answer would probably need to consider string parsing rather than int casting.

Comment: Agree that `@EnumType.One` will give you *One*.  We'll @Cfun decide.  You can pass it either way.

Comment: @KurtHamilton Since i cannot declare my parameter straightforward as an enum type (in fact it is overriding a property of a base class omitted code to simplify the question to the essential) for me it is the same to convert string or int -> enum. using string will have bigger modification code compared to the added value (for my use case of course).